# Android Custom Rectangle Drawing

Tags: android, android-layout

I am looking to create a Scrabble board type view in my Android UI.  For this I have currently decided (still toying on with the best way to do this) on using a TableLayout and TableRow views with custom BoardCell views as the individual cells of the board.

I am still new to Android and I have never created a custom View before.  I have run into an issue drawing the rectangle.  I can get the first cell of a row to draw but I can not get the remaining 14 cells in that row to be drawn.  During debugging all BoardCell objects are initialised and 'onDraw' is called for each.  Measurements and left,top,right and bottom positions appear to be correct as well.  So my question is... what am I doing wrong?  That must be something simple I am missing?

I have tried simply drawing the stroke of some of the cells (as in code below) and the right and bottom lines are missing.  I know this has something to do with it but I can't see why the right and bottom of the cell would not be drawn?

Here is all the relevant code below, irrelevant code removed to shorten this post.

activity_game.xml

`<!-- Game Board -->
    <TableLayout android:id="@+id/board_grid"
                 android:layout_width="355dp"
                 android:layout_height="355dp"
                 android:layout_below="@+id/score_container"
                 android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                 android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                 android:background="@color/white"
                 android:stretchColumns="*">
        <!-- Row 1 -->
        <TableRow android:layout_weight="1">
            <BoardCellView android:layout_height="21dp" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_margin="1dp" custom:cellType="doubleWord"/>
            <BoardCellView android:layout_height="21dp" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_margin="1dp"/>
            <BoardCellView android:layout_height="21dp" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_margin="1dp"/>
            <BoardCellView android:layout_height="21dp" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_margin="1dp"/>
            <BoardCellView android:layout_height="21dp" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_margin="1dp"/>
            <BoardCellView android:layout_height="21dp" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_margin="1dp"/>
            <BoardCellView android:layout_height="21dp" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_margin="1dp" custom:cellType="doubleLetter"/>
            <BoardCellView android:layout_height="21dp" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_margin="1dp"/>
            <BoardCellView android:layout_height="21dp" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_margin="1dp" custom:cellType="doubleLetter"/>
            <BoardCellView android:layout_height="21dp" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_margin="1dp"/>
            <BoardCellView android:layout_height="21dp" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_margin="1dp"/>
            <BoardCellView android:layout_height="21dp" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_margin="1dp"/>
            <BoardCellView android:layout_height="21dp" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_margin="1dp"/>
            <BoardCellView android:layout_height="21dp" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_margin="1dp"/>
            <BoardCellView android:layout_height="21dp" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_margin="1dp" custom:cellType="doubleWord"/>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>`

BoardCellView.java

```
public class BoardCellView extends View {

    private static final String TAG = BoardCellView.class.getName();

    private static final int STANDARD_CELL_COLOUR       = Color.rgb(234, 234, 234);
    private static final int DOUBLE_LETTER_CELL_COLOUR  = Color.rgb(200, 175, 224);
    private static final int TRIPLE_LETTER_CELL_COLOUR  = Color.rgb(132, 217, 168);
    private static final int DOUBLE_WORD_CELL_COLOUR    = Color.rgb(255, 181, 131);
    private static final int TRIPLE_WORD_CELL_COLOUR    = Color.rgb(146, 205, 251);

    private Paint standardCellPaint;
    private Paint doubleLetterPaint;
    private Paint tripleLetterPaint;
    private Paint doubleWordPaint;
    private Paint tripleWordPaint;

    private CellType cellType;

    private Rect cellRectangle;

    public BoardCellView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        init();

        TypedArray typedArray = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(
            attrs,
            R.styleable.BoardCellView,
            0, 0);

        try {
            this.cellType =     CellType.fromInt(typedArray.getInt(R.styleable.BoardCellView_cellType, 0));

        } finally {
            typedArray.recycle();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Setup the paint and rectangle objects
     */
    private void init() {
        // The rectangle we will use to draw
        this.cellRectangle = new Rect();

        // Setup the Paints for each cell type
        this.standardCellPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        this.standardCellPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        this.standardCellPaint.setColor(STANDARD_CELL_COLOUR);
        this.standardCellPaint.setStrokeWidth(5.0f);

        this.doubleLetterPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        this.doubleLetterPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        this.doubleLetterPaint.setColor(DOUBLE_LETTER_CELL_COLOUR);

        this.tripleLetterPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        this.tripleLetterPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        this.tripleLetterPaint.setColor(TRIPLE_LETTER_CELL_COLOUR);

        this.doubleWordPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        this.doubleWordPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        this.doubleWordPaint.setColor(DOUBLE_WORD_CELL_COLOUR);
        this.doubleWordPaint.setStrokeWidth(5.0f);

        this.tripleWordPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        this.tripleWordPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        this.tripleWordPaint.setColor(TRIPLE_WORD_CELL_COLOUR);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
        this.cellRectangle.set(left, top, right, bottom);
        Log.d(TAG, "---- " + left + ":"+ top + ":"+ right + ":"+ bottom);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        // Standard cell first as this is by far the most common
        switch (this.cellType) {
            case STANDARD:
                Log.d(TAG, "---- Drawing Standard: " + this.cellRectangle.toShortString());
                canvas.drawRect(this.cellRectangle, this.standardCellPaint);
                break;
            case DL:
                Log.d(TAG, "---- Drawing DL");
                canvas.drawRect(this.cellRectangle, this.doubleLetterPaint);
                break;
            case TL:
                Log.d(TAG, "---- Drawing TL");
                canvas.drawRect(this.cellRectangle, this.tripleLetterPaint);
                break;
            case DW:
                Log.d(TAG, "---- Drawing DW: " + this.cellRectangle.toShortString());
                canvas.drawRect(this.cellRectangle, this.doubleWordPaint);
                break;
            case TW:
                Log.d(TAG, "---- Drawing TW");
                canvas.drawRect(this.cellRectangle, this.tripleWordPaint);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Output from Logcat(first is output from onLayout, second is from onDraw)

```
BoardCellView﹕ ---- 3:3:68:66
03-27 10:57:12.534  27810-27810/app D/BoardCellView﹕ ---- 74:3:139:66
03-27 10:57:12.534  27810-27810/app D/BoardCellView﹕ ---- 145:3:210:66
03-27 10:57:12.534  27810-27810/app D/BoardCellView﹕ ---- 216:3:281:66
03-27 10:57:12.534  27810-27810/app D/BoardCellView﹕ ---- 287:3:352:66
03-27 10:57:12.536  27810-27810/app D/BoardCellView﹕ ---- 358:3:423:66
....
---- Drawing DW: [3,3][68,66]
03-27 10:57:12.576  27810-27810/app D/BoardCellView﹕ ---- Drawing Standard: [74,3][139,66]
03-27 10:57:12.576  27810-27810/app D/BoardCellView﹕ ---- Drawing Standard: [145,3][210,66]
03-27 10:57:12.576  27810-27810/app D/BoardCellView﹕ ---- Drawing Standard: [216,3][281,66]
03-27 10:57:12.576  27810-27810/app D/BoardCellView﹕ ---- Drawing Standard: [287,3][352,66]
```

Here is how the view is drawn.  First 2 rows use my custom views.  Remaining rows use simple View objects with a background colour.

![board view]http://cl.ly/image/0T2F3i1l3y24

I have spent a few days on this trying various solutions from Google and here ([Drawing multiple custom views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26446919/drawing-multiple-custom-views)) but I have not found anything that fixes my problem.  Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the setting of `cellRectangle` in `onLayout()`. The rectangle co-ordinates passed into `onLayout()` are relative to the parent view, however the co-ordinates that you need to use in `onDraw()` when calling `drawRect()` should be relative to the view itself, because the `Canvas` is set up so that the top left of the view corresponds to (0, 0).

So (left, top) in the parent view is going to correspond to (0, 0) in the child view, and (right, bottom) is going to correspond to (right-left, bottom-top). You just have to subtract (left, top) from both of them basically.

With that in mind, change `onLayout` like this:

```
@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
    this.cellRectangle.set(0, 0, right-left, bottom-top);
    Log.d(TAG, "---- " + left + ":"+ top + ":"+ right + ":"+ bottom);
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  That makes total sense.  I guess because the co-ordinates printed out in debug where the co-ordinates of the parent view I assumed the Canvas in the onDraw was actually the Canvas of the parent the View's were to be drawn in/onto.  I knew it had to be a simple oversight somewhere on my behalf.